# Adding POST Params to render json methods in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, models, parameters

I have a method called is_following in the user.rb model, and it checks to see if one user is following another.

Users Controller

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
       respond_to |format|
          format.json { render json: @user, :methods => [:image_url, :is_following] }
       end
```

User Model

```
  def is_following params
    return "yep" if params[:follower_id] == id
  end
```

However, I don't know how to pass params into the :is_following method in the controller. Anyone have any luck or solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the answer you're looking for but it definitely a solution. I recommend you stop using `render` to generate your JSON.

Gems such as [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) or [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) make it easier and gives you more flexibility.

Ruby on Rails is a MVC framework. You should leave view generation at the view layer. Doing this will save you from much more pain you'll endure in the future.

Comment: Wow, that would've saved me a ton of time... like a month ago ha. There's so much of this app already built on this method of generating json responses, I don't really want to migrate back now :(

Comment: Think about this. How much time will it maintenance save you in the future migrating? Right now, you're at the mercy of how ActiveRecord generates JSON.